# merge columns that have the same name r

Tags: r, merge, mongolite

I am working in R with a dataset that is created from mongodb with the use of mongolite.
I am getting a list that looks like so:

```
   _id A  B  A  B  A  B  NA NA
    1  a  1  b  2  e  5  NA NA 
    2  k  4  l  3  c  3  d  4
```

I would like to merge the datasetto look like this:

```
   _id A  B 
    1  a  1
    2  k  4
    1  b  2
    2  l  3
    1  e  5
    2  c  3
    1  NA NA
    2  d  4
```

The `NAs` in the last columns are there because the columns are named from the first entry and if a later entry has more columns than that they don't get names assigned to them, (if I get help for this as well it would be awesome but it's not the reason I am here).
Also the number of columns might differ for different subsets of the dataset. 
I have tried `melt()` but since it is a list and not a dataframe it doesn't work as expected, I have tried `stack()` but it dodn't work because the columns have the same name and some of them don't even have a name. 
I know this is a very weird situation and appreciate any help. 
Thank you.

Comment: What does the data set actually look like when you get it into R? Please share it with `dput(name_of_dataset)`

Comment: @jdobres `dput()` gave the following: 
` `1` = structure(c("1", "a", "1", "b", "2", "e", "5"), .Names = c("_id", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B")), `2` = structure(c("2", "k", "4", "l", "3", "c", "3", "d", "4"), .Names = c("_id", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B")) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help, they were great inspirations.
Even though @Andre Elrico gave a solution that worked in the reproducible example better @phiver gave a solution that worked better on my overall problem. 
By using both those I came up with the following.

```
library(data.table)
#The data were in a list of lists called list for this example
temp <- as.data.table(matrix(t(sapply(list, '[', seq(max(sapply(list, lenth))))), 
                            nrow = m)) 
# m here is the number of lists in list

cols <- names(temp)
cols[grep(pattern = "^V", x = cols)] <- c("B", "A") 
#They need to be the opposite way because the first column is going to be substituted with id, and this way they fall on the correct column after that
cols[1] <- "id"
names(temp) <- cols
l <- melt.data.table(temp, id.vars = 1, 
                           measure.vars = patterns(c("A", "B")), 
                           value.name = c("A", "B"))
```

That way I can use this also if I have more than 2 columns that I need to manipulate like that.

Answer (score 0):

using `library(magrittr)`

data:

```
df <- fread("
               _id A  B  A  B  A  B  NA NA
    1  a  1  b  2  e  5  NA NA 
    2  k  4  l  3  c  3  d  4 ",header=T)
setDF(df)
```

Code:

```
df2 <- df[,-1]

odds<- df2 %>% ncol %>% {(1:.)%%2} %>% as.logical
even<- df2 %>% ncol %>% {!(1:.)%%2}

cbind(df[,1,drop=F],
      A=unlist(df2[,odds]),
      B=unlist(df2[,even]),
      row.names=NULL)
```

result:

```
#   _id    A  B
# 1   1    a  1
# 2   2    k  4
# 3   1    b  2
# 4   2    l  3
# 5   1    e  5
# 6   2    c  3
# 7   1 <NA> NA
# 8   2    d  4
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`. Assuming A and B are always following each other. I created an example with 2 sets of NA's in the header. With grep we can find the ones `fread` has named V8 etc. Using R's recycling of vectors, you can rename multiple headers in one go. If in your case these are named differently change the pattern in the grep command. Then we melt the data in via melt

```
library(data.table)

df <- fread("
               _id A  B  A  B  A  B  NA NA NA NA
                1  a  1  b  2  e  5  NA NA NA NA
                2  k  4  l  3  c  3  d  4 e 5",
            header = TRUE)

df
   _id A B A B A B    A  B    A  B
1:   1 a 1 b 2 e 5 <NA> NA <NA> NA
2:   2 k 4 l 3 c 3    d  4    e  5

# assuming A B are always following each other. Can be done in 1 statement.
cols <- names(df)
cols[grep(pattern = "^V", x = cols)] <- c("A", "B")
names(df) <- cols

# melt data (if df is a data.frame replace df with setDT(df)
df_melted <- melt(df, id.vars = 1, 
                  measure.vars = patterns(c('A', 'B')),
                  value.name=c('A', 'B'))

df_melted
    _id variable    A  B
 1:   1        1    a  1
 2:   2        1    k  4
 3:   1        2    b  2
 4:   2        2    l  3
 5:   1        3    e  5
 6:   2        3    c  3
 7:   1        4 <NA> NA
 8:   2        4    d  4
 9:   1        5 <NA> NA
10:   2        5    e  5
```

Comment: I run this and it doesn't work, 
The `cols` variable is not changed after the transformation and the `df_melted`looks like this 
    `_id variable  A  B
     1:   1        1  a  1
     2:   2        1  k  4
     3:   1        2  b  2
     4:   2        2  l  3
     5:   1        3  e  5
     6:   2        3  c  3
     7:   1        4 NA NA
     8:   2        4  d NA
     9:   1        5 NA NA
   10:   2        5  4 NA
   11:   1        6 NA NA
   12:   2        6  e NA
   13:   1        7 NA NA
   14:   2        7  5 NA`